# How to compute the sum of a $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ serie?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms

I'm solving few math puzzles to train myself for a local math contest, and I'm stuck with this problem :

Compute the sum of :

$$\frac{1}{2*1} + \frac{1}{2*3} + \frac{1}{3*4} + ... + \frac{1}{2013*2014}$$

As said in the title, I know that all of those, can be written as : 
$\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$

But the $n(n+1)$ is not a geo seq nor an arithmetic one . So there are no theorems to compute their sum .

I'v also found a good number of similar puzzles so how can I solve this kind of problems ?

Comment: [Telescoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series): $$\dfrac1{n(n+1)}=\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n+1}.$$

Comment: See also these questions (they're about infinite series, but what matters is the general strategy): [$\sum \limits_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r(r+1)}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/7136/201168) and the related questions [mentioned here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1684547/how-to-calculate-sum-k-1%e2%88%9e-frac1kk1#comment3437951_1684547), such as, [$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r(r+3)}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/588802/201168), [$\sum\limits_{r=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(r-1)r(r+1)}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/124277/201168).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\frac{1}{n(n+1)} $ is called a telescopic sum, which telescopically can be expressed as : $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}  = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}$, which simplifies your initial expression. (This is the way that you express the series sum too).